# Document class silently fails

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have this weird issue while compiling my .fla file : it won't use the Document class. Here is the document class. (note that the parent class EditorPlugin extends Sprite).

```
package com.myproject.plugins.editor {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.myproject.editor.EditorPlugin;
import com.myproject.editor.tools.EpisodeEditorTool;
import com.myproject.editor.tools.NewTabTool;
import com.myproject.editor.tools.ToolManager;

public class EpisodeEditorPlugin extends EditorPlugin{
    public function EpisodeEditorPlugin(){
        trace("creating", this);
        AddAuth(ToolManager.EDIT_EPISODE_AUTH, ToolManager.EDIT_EPISODE_AUTH, EpisodeEditorTool, ToolManager.EDIT_EPISODE_LABEL);
    }
}
}
```

The weird part is that in the line below, if I use NewTabTool instead of EpisodeEditorTool, the code works just fine, but with EpisodeEditorTool, the Class is not instanciated. There are no warnings or compiling errors, but i don't get the trace. I loaded the resulting .swf, it is not of type EpisodeEditorPlugin, but rather a simple MovieClip (*via* getQualifiedClassName() and is EpisodeEditorPlugin).

The EpisodeEditorTool and NewTabTool are quite similar even though of different use, but very huge, here are their declarations :

```
public class EpisodeEditorTool extends JPanel implements ITool{
```

and

```
public class NewTabTool extends JPanel implements ITool{
```

I should add that both class contain no error (at least according to Flash) and have been compiled in other .flas before. the only problem I can see is that EpisodeEditorTool is even more huge(r?) than other ITools.

Does anyone have any idea of how a document class could fail to be applied? And fail silently at that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can really think of is that you're not specifying the name of the Document class correctly inside the Flash IDE. Inside the Properties panel there's a box where you enter the name of your Document class, which you must presumably have used if the Document class works when you rename the class to `NewTabTool`. I guess you put NewTabTool into that box, then changed the actual class' name, and forgot to change the reference in the Properties panel. I've forgotten that little bit when changing the name of my Document class before, I hope your solution is as simple as that!

debu

Comment: Oh I wish it was so simple :/

Turns out the flash compiler was crumbling under too much work (too many classes, appearently), and failed in silence.

I stopped using one heavy ASWing component, and nows works (almost) like a charm :)